# What is the equivalent resistance between Nodes A and B in this infinite resistor network?

Tags: resistors, circuit-analysis

Please provide analytical solutions or instructions and not simulation results.
Thanks.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkETMR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: Homework questions with no attempt at a solution are closed.

Comment: @LeonHeller this is not a homework question and I'm not a student anymore!

Comment: What physical system is this modeling?

Comment: @EdTate I don't think any. I was just taking a look at my old papers and happened to see this question and tried to solve it. not successful yet!

Comment: How is this an infinite resistor network? I cannot see how.

Comment: Whether someone actually assigned this question to you as homework or not is immaterial to the nature/content of your question *here*. Also most of these infinite network (brain teaser) problems are found in math papers/books rather than in EE ones... which kinda makes them off-topic-ish even with attempts included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The horizontal resistors have no current in them because the circuit is symmetrical when mirrored in the X-axis. They can be ignored.

Starting at the centre, you have some network X with 2 R's in series and then an R  and a 2R in parallel. R//2R is 2/3R.

So at the n+1st iteration, you have (// means parallel)

Rn1 = (2R+Rn)//(2R/3)  = (2R + Rn)*(2R/3) / (8R/3 + Rn)

In the limit, Rn1 = Rn == RX (if the sequence converges, which it must), so you get

Rx = (2R + Rx)*(2R/3) / (8R/3 + Rx)
8R*Rx/3 + Rx^2 = 4R^2/3 + 2R*RX/3

8R*Rx + 3Rx^2 = 4R^2 + 2R*Rx

3Rx^2 + 6R*Rx - 2R^2 = 0

This has a negative root, and a positive one at +0.291*R

So the total resistance is 0.291*R

You can check if the recursion holds:
Start with 0.291, add 2 in series = 2.291, then in parallel with that there is 1, and 2:
1/(Rn+1) = 1/2.291 + 1/1 + 1/2 = 1/0.291 ==> Correct.

Comment: it looks correct except for that you have missed a 2R resistance in parallel to R and (2R+Rn). please edit your answer so I can check it as correct. thanks!